# How to make WordPress customizer to autoload changes?

Tags: theme-customizer

I have used the add theme support for custom background and it applies changes only on save, but i want to enable the live preview of what i am doing. How to enable the auto-load for the customizer ?

Comment: that is weird, you mean when you select a color in the color-picker in the customizer, the live preview is not being updated? WP 4.7 ?

Comment: yes...just on save.. to be mentioned i am developing from scratch so i may be missing something i don't know

Comment: its there any error in the console?, i just did a quick test in a barebone theme and when clicking in a color it changes in the right side.

Comment: actually the console has a bunch of errors coming from load-styles.php when inspect on customizer screen. but i don't know why because it is completely from scratch theme

Comment: a link to download the theme [link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/fohkcugxfz092ry/Tutorial+Blog.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your theme, you need to change the name of the folder, there cant be spaces in the name:

`Tutorial Blog` -> `tutorialblog` or maybe `tutorial-blog`

If you are following a tutorial find other, because i dont think this one is using the guide of the WordPress codex.

**EDIT:**
(from the user)
Add `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` to the theme usually in `footer.php`

Comment: Thanks for you time,but i have made the change but still not solved, Have you testes it and found it works?.. and i am not following any tutorial i refer to codex and try to apply functions one by one. for learning purposes

Comment: yeah, the background is changing on click, did you select another theme then activated your theme again? after changing the name

Comment: i did unfortunately. i don't know what the problem is

Comment: Finally i have found where the problem is, and it is that i haven't added the `wp_footer` function yet to the theme, so i did and with a combination of your answer of renaming the theme folder, now it works fine. please update your answer, i shall accept it

Comment: oh that is true i added <?php wp_footer(); ?> to the footer.php